# On the existence of a chain with empty intersection

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory

Let $X$ be a family of sets such that each of them has more than one element and whenever $A\cup B$ is a partition of an element of $X$ then either $A \in X$ or $B\in X$. I am trying to show that there is a chain of elements of $X$ with empty intersection. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Use Zorn's lemma. Or, if you rather, build the chain by transfinite induction.

Comment: This seems familiar. I think someone had asked that before, but I'm not sure.

Comment: When you say "either $A\in X$ or $B\in X$" do you mean at least one of them, or exactly one of them?

Comment: A (more interesting) similar problem was asked here:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496668/alternative-argument-set-theory-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $Y$ the set of chains of $X$, partially ordered ordered by inclusion. It's easy to see that we can use Zorn on $Y$, so take a maximal chain $M\subset X$. If the intersection $\bigcap M$ of the elements of $M$ is empty, we have finished. If it is not, we have two cases. First case, $\cap M \in X$, but then is obvious how to make a chain longer than $M$(here we use that elements of $X$ have more than one element), absurd. Second case, $\cap M \notin X$. But then, if we take the elements of $M$ and subtract to them $\cap M$, we get other elements of $X$ that form a chain, and this new chain has, obviously, empty intersection.

Comment: If $\bigcap M=\{a,b\}$, why can you make the chain longer? (You need to show, first, that $X$ have no finite elements. Then the case here cannot happen.)

Comment: That's right, but I don't need it. I only need to write $\bigcap X=A\cup B$ non-trivially. And for this it's enough the hypothesis, nothing else.

Comment: Obviously, I intended $\bigcap M$, not $\bigcap X$, sorry.